# Using COM interfaces with initialized OUT parameters via Python comtypes library

Tags: python, com, comtypes

I'm using a 3rd-party C++ library (exporting a typelib via COM) from Python via the [comtypes](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/comtypes) module.

One of the available calls defines an OUT parameter, like so:

```
COMMETHOD([helpstring(u'method GetPacket')], HRESULT, 'GetPacket',
          ( ['in'], comtypes.gen._00020430_0000_0000_C000_000000000046_0_2_0.GUID, 'guid' ),
          ( ['in'], c_int, 'lSize' ),
          ( ['out'], POINTER(c_ubyte), 'pData' )),
```

The C++ example code provided by the library's author initializes `pData` to be a byte array of length `lSize` before invoking `GetPacket()`, like so:

```
pPacket = new BYTE[lSize];
HRESULT hr = pData->GetPacket(guid, lSize, pPacket);
```

However, the comtypes library for Python doesn't provide a way to pass an initial value for `pData` -- and, on calling the library with no initial value, the interpreter promptly segfaults.

Is it possible to interoperate with this library from Python -- ideally, from `comtypes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with some low-level changes to the generated `GetPacket`.

Source: [[comtypes-users] Right way to call a method with a pointer to array?](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=4F1D33F9.2030304%40tudelft.nl&forum_name=comtypes-users)

```
# change GetPacket so the second argument is in, not out
packet = (c_ubyte * size)()
data.GetPacket(guid, size, packet)
```

However, note that typelibs don't contain information about `size_is`, `length_is` and a [few other things](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/236970/en-us). This means that the generic typelib marshaller proxies and stubs, used across apartment and process boundaries, will not look into `lSize` to determine how many elements to serialize from `pData`, it'll always (try to) serialize a single pointed item.

In other words, that kind of code, whether C++ or Python, will only work in the same apartment.

Comment: I'm too struggling to implement PortableDevice COM API in my python application using comtype and got stuck where I'm not able to pass correct param to COM method. @acelent, can you please pass your contact detail... I need paid consultancy from expert like you.

Comment: @NilayAnand, I can't do that, I'm sorry. I'll take a look at two of your questions related with Python and COM whenever I have some time, but for this kind of support, you should probably ask the comtypes authors or maintainers.